# dredge doesn't work when specifying glmer optimizer

Tags: r, lme4, mumin

I am trying to use `dredge` from the R package `MuMIn` with a global binomial `glmer` model. I find that I need to specify the optimizer with `control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa")` for convergence. However, when I go to use `dredge`, I get an error. If I reduce the number of predictors in the model, I can remove the `bobyqa` specification, get convergence, and use dredge. Any way I can get `dredge` to go with `glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa")`?

```
test.glob=glmer(exploitpark~X + as.factor(Y) + Z + A + B + (1|ID), 
                family=binomial(), 
                glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), data=df)
options(na.action = "na.fail")   #  prevent fitting models to different datasets
test.Set = dredge(test.glob, beta=c("partial.sd"), extra = c("R^2"))

Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
```

> Error in glm.control(optimizer = c("bobyqa", "bobyqa"), calc.derivs = TRUE,  : 
>     unused arguments (optimizer = c("bobyqa", "bobyqa"), calc.derivs = TRUE, use.last.params = FALSE, restart_edge = FALSE, boundary.tol = 1e-05, tolPwrss = 1e-07, compDev = TRUE, nAGQ0initStep = TRUE, checkControl = list(check.nobs.vs.rankZ = "ignore", check.nobs.vs.nlev = "stop", check.nlev.gtreq.5 = "ignore", check.nlev.gtr.1 = "stop", check.nobs.vs.nRE = "stop", check.rankX = "message+drop.cols", check.scaleX = "warning", check.formula.LHS = "stop", check.response.not.const = "stop"), checkConv = list(check.conv.grad = list(
>       action = "warning", tol = 0.001, relTol = NULL), check.conv.singular = list(action = "message", tol = 1e-04), check.conv.hess = list(action = "warning", tol = 1e-06)), optCtrl = list())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** probably a bug in `MuMIn::dredge()` - I'm still digging - but it seems to work OK if you leave out the `extra="R^2"` specification.

### reproducible example

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(200),x2=rnorm(200),x3=rnorm(200),
                 f=factor(rep(1:10,each=20)),
                 n=50)
library(lme4)
dd$y <- simulate(~x1+x2+x3+(1|f),
                 family=binomial,
                 weights=dd$n,
                 newdata=dd,
                 newparams=list(beta=c(1,1,1,1),
                                theta=1))[[1]] 
## fit model
m0 <- glmer(y~x1+x2+x3+(1|f),
            family=binomial,
            weights=n,
            data=dd,
            na.action="na.fail")
```

### now try glmer()+dredge(), with and without optimizer specification

```
library(MuMIn)
d0 <- dredge(m0)
m1 <- update(m0, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
d1 <- dredge(m1)
```

These all work - so the problem must be with some of the optional arguments. Testing that:

```
d0B <- dredge(m0, beta=c("partial.sd"), extra = c("R^2")) ## works
d1B <- try(dredge(m1, beta=c("partial.sd"), extra = c("R^2"))) ## fails
```

Which of the extra arguments is the culprit?

```
d1C <- dredge(m1, beta=c("partial.sd"))  ## works
d1D <- try(dredge(m1, extra=c("R^2")))   ## fails
```

---

If you really, really want your R^2 values you could download/unpack the source code to the package, edit line 101 of `R/r.squaredLR.R` as indicated below (add `cl$control` to the list of elements that are set to `NULL`, and re-install the package ...

```
===================================================================
--- R/r.squaredLR.R (revision 443)
+++ R/r.squaredLR.R (working copy)
@@ -98,7 +98,7 @@
        if(formulaArgName != "formula")
            names(cl)[names(cl) == formulaArgName] <- "formula"
        cl$formula <- update(as.formula(cl$formula), . ~ 1)
-       cl$method <- cl$start <- cl$offset <- contrasts <- NULL
+       cl$method <- cl$start <- cl$offset <- cl$control <- contrasts <- NULL
    }
    cl <- cl[c(TRUE, names(cl)[-1L] %in% names(call2arg(cl)))]
    if(evaluate) eval(cl, envir = envir) else cl
```

Comment: Aha. Indeed, removing extra = c("R^2")) does the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in `r.squaredLR` (implied by `extra = "R^2"`), which tries to fit a `glm` null model with `glmer`'s argument `control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa")`. (I will try to implement a solution for this bug  in the forthcoming version of MuMIn.)

In case of `glmer` (or mixed models in general) it may be better to use `r.squaredGLMM` rather than `r.squaredLR`. So you would need to provide `dredge` with a function that extracts the R^2 vector from the result of `r.squaredGLMM` (which returns a `matrix`). For example:

```
# (following Ben Bolker's example above))
# Fit a null model with RE (use a non-exported function .nullFitRE or specify it by hand:
nullmodel <- MuMIn:::.nullFitRE(m1)
# the above step is not necessary, but avoids repeated re-fitting of the null model.

dredge(m1, beta="partial.sd", extra =list(R2 = function(x) {
    r.squaredGLMM(x, null = nullmodel)["delta", ]
}))
```